# Using FileNameFinder class in SoapUI Groovy Scripting

Tags: groovy, ant, soapui, ready-api

I am trying to mock a service whose request input parameter could be either Name or UniqueIdentifier. The response returned is the same for both the input types.

So, I want to name the files `<Name>_<UniqueIdentifier>.xml` and read the mock responses from a directory.

When the request is received on the mock, I want to search the file with input parameter (which will be substring of the file name in the directory) and dispatch the response.

For this I am trying to use the FileNameFinder class however I get

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
>   org/apache/tools/ant/BuildException

I have also tried with ant.jar under  `C:\Program Files\SmartBear\ReadyAPI-1.8.5\lib`. But, I get the same error.

Would appreciate if you could assist with this issue.

Thanks.

**dispatch script in ReadyAPI**

```
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils(context);
def holder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder("externalBnSearch#Request");
import groovy.util.FileNameFinder;

String name = holder.getNodeValue( "//tn.type:name" )
log.info('Request - name: ' + name);

String UNI = holder.getNodeValue( "//tn.type:UNI" )
log.info('Request - number: ' +UNI);

def file = new FileNameFinder().getFileNames("C:/resposne/", '"+name+"*/*.xml')
log.info(txtFiles)

def mockname = "LookUpResponse"

if (file.exists())  
{
context.content = file.getText()
return (mockname);
}
```

Comment: What version of ant is your `ant.jar`?

Comment: 1. why ant involved? 2. can you show sample request? 3. are all the responses in the same directory? 4. are there files starts with same names if the request has only name, then what do you want to do? Finally what is happening with the above script? any errors?

Comment: apologies for the delayed response. ant.jar version is 1.6.5

Comment: @ Rao 1)  read on the internet that FileNameFinder is an ant supported class and  one of the solution mentioned was to try adding ant.jar to readyapi lib. 2) have attached a sample request. 3) yes all the response in the same directory. 4. all files wud have unique names 5. with FileNameFinder function I am getting the error java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/BuildException

Comment: @newtogroovy `ant.jar` is not really related with `FileNameFinder` this class is in the groovy `gdk`. Really the problem ` java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/ant/BuildException` is not related with `FileNameFinder` it's probably about the orchestration of your script execution.